# Get class name and property name from an expression () => MyClass.Name

Tags: .net, linq, expression

This is mot likely a duplicate, but I couldn't find a proper question.

I want to get `"MyClass.Name"` from `() => MyClass.Name`. How do I define the method parameter and how do I convert the expression to a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is an `Expression<Func<string>>`, so you could have:

```
void Foo(Expression<Func<string>> selector) {...}
```

or

```
void Foo<T>(Expression<Func<T>> selector) {...}
```

however, note that the syntax `MyClass.Name` refers to a *static* property; if you want an *instance* property you might need something more like an `Expression<Func<MyClass,string>>` - for example:

```
static void Foo<TSource, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector)
{

}
static void Main() {
     Foo((MyClass obj) => obj.Name);        
}
```

As for implementation; **in this simple case**, we can expect the `Body` to be a `MemberExpression`, so:

```
static void Foo<TSource, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector)
{
    var member = ((MemberExpression)selector.Body).Member;
    Console.WriteLine(member.ReflectedType.Name + "." + member.Name);
}
```

However, it is more complex in the general case. This will also work if we use the static member:

```
static void Foo<TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TValue>> selector)
{
    var member = ((MemberExpression)selector.Body).Member;
    Console.WriteLine(member.ReflectedType.Name + "." + member.Name);
}
```

Comment: `Foo((MyClass obj) => obj.Name)` was what I were looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether `Name` is static property.
1.If it is not static then `MyClass.Name` will not be a valid syntax at all. So let's assume that in this case you want to get `class+property` from local variable usage like this:

```
var instance = new MyClass();
string result = GetClassAndPropertyName(() => instance.Name);
```

So the implementation for `GetClassAndPropertyName` should be like this:

```
public static string GetClassAndPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) e.Body;
    return memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType.Name + "." + memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

Another syntax you can find in Marc's answer.

2.`Name` property could also be static, which is unlikely on my opinion, but it will allow following syntax, which is exact syntax as you have asked for:

```
string result = GetClassAndPropertyName(() => MyClass.Name);
```